# Powershell script run System.IO.FileSystemWatcher as Windows service

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, service

I need a FileWatcher script to detect new files and execute another powershell script if the files are found. The destination directory of this 2nd PS script outputs file to a UNC mount that has the directory mounted as P: . That UNC mount is actually a SMB share from a Linux machine. That Linux machine hosts a SMB service with access granted to one linux user on the box. That linux user has the proper rights to create and modify the files within the SMB directory.

I can get the filewatcher script to perform the actions perfectly fine if I run the script in a live window while I am logged in.

I cannot get the filewatcher script to run as a windows service and properly execute a command after the System.IO.FileSystemWatcher detects a new file.

I used the winsw.exe format to create the Windows Service.
When I run this as the SYSTEM user...nothing.
When I run the service as myself, the same user that successfully runs it in a live window, nothing.

Here is the winsw.xml

```
<service>
<id>StartWatchingFiles</id>
<name>Start Watching Files</name>
<description>This is used to watch files.</description>
<executable>PowerShell.exe</executable>
<logmode>reset</logmode>
<arguments>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\scripts\StartWatching.ps1"</arguments>
</service>
```

After this runs, the files are generated and the watcher script will not fire off the PS script in response to that newly detected file.

Comment: Does the ACL on the path you're watching include access for the SYSTEM account?

Comment: How does the P: drive get mapped?

Comment: Clayton - It does include SYSTEM. All access.

Comment: Clayton - It does include SYSTEM w/ all perms. Twisty - I have a script that maps it and it is already mapped as a fail safe during testing. Neither proved to work. When mapping through he powershell script, I used the NET USE w/ credentials baked in. the script works when firing it off manually as the user logged in